# How do I use PHPMailer with Outlook Exchange?

Tags: php, email, exchange-server, phpmailer

I've searched all around for some information on sending email with PHP, and it seems that PHPMailer is the way to go.

I don't understand much about SMTP and how mail is generated, so I'm not sure what to do in order to get started here.

My company uses Microsoft Exchange on the backend, and Microsoft Outlook 2007 on the frontend.  I am trying to write some PHP code that will utilize this to send an email, but I (surprisingly) can't find anything online about how to do this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

More specifically,  the PHPMailer example lists these items:

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
```

But I have no idea where to find this information apart from username and password.

Comment: Is this on a separate machine or are you running PHP on the Windows server?

Comment: open your copy of outlook go to the accounts setting page, you should find the server name\port. may not be best to use your own account - i would set up a new one in exchange for thsi

Comment: @Machavity This is on a separate machine - I don't have access to our company's Windows server.

Comment: @Dagon - my goal is to allow various users from within the company to send out emails from this program FROM their own email address within the company, not from a standardized `blahblah@company.com` email address.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Dagon, I get this crazy long URL.... can this be correct?  `17268-998e-4a55-b85b-a70e8643421g@company.com`

Comment: the user can fill in the form with their address, and it can look like it came from their address, but it doesn't have to be sent from their actual account

Comment: it could be - dont suppose there's who ever set up the exchange server to ask :-)

Comment: Okay - I can definitely get a new account set up for this - I can use mine for now just to test though, but I still don't know where to find the SMTP & port information...

Comment: From a technical standpoint you don't need to log into people's accounts to send mail from their address. You can send mail from anyone from any server via sendmail or etc; you just would need to ensure spf records and dkim/domainkeys are doing their job.

Comment: @skrilled, even better!  But still, I don't know where to start finding the server information....